# Phrase meaning: fall as much as 90%

Tags: meaning

Does the following quote mean the native population dropped to 90% of the original numbers or by 90%, that is to 10% of the original value?

> [...] the native population of New Spain fell as much as 90% from its original numbers in the 16th century.

Comment: It's not very clear. I would take it to mean that at its lowest point, the population of New Spain was only 10% of its original population in the 16th c.

Answer (score 2):

This phrase means that the native population fell to 10% of its original numbers in the 16th century. It fell by 90%. Hope this helps. Also see:
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+by

Answer (score 1):

"Fell as much as 90%" means that afterward, only 10% of the population may have remained. For example, if a population of 100 fell by 85%, the population is now 15.

Comment: The question is about the phrase in the quote, not OP's interpretation

Comment: @M.A.R. Perhaps the confusion came from me using "dropped by" instead of "fell as much as." I've edited the answer to correct that.